# Help me identify an old children's picture book featuring anthropomimetic arthropods

Tags: identification-request

The book in question was written prior to 1990.  The pages probably had no words — I was able to read at the time, so either it was not narrated or the words were not memorable.  Each page, or pair of pages, featured a scene in some fictional town which resembled a human town but populated by arthropods:  insects, spiders.  The arthropods were not anthropomorphic, but assuming the roles of humans in that town.  E.g.

- At a dinner table, a father daddy-long-legs (harvestman) was seated at the head of a table as a pillbug was being served on a platter.  The mother was a preying mantis IIRC.
- A large centipede was crawling down a street, colored like a school bus. 
  I can't remember if the other insects were riding on it, or if the bus simply resembled a centipede on the outside.

The pages had about the same ratio as the Magic School Bus books IIRC.

Comment: This book sounds terrifying.

Comment: @Matrim I'm not sure I agree with you re untagging [tag:comics]. The question asks about a book composed mostly of pictures, and [the OP agreed with the tag](http://literature.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1157).

Comment: @Shoket But this book is not a comic, so it should not be tagged as thus.

Comment: @Shokhet many children books are composed mostly of pictures, but that does not make them Comics

Comment: @Riker that's what i thought too, but most of the definitions i saw returned from a websearch disagreed.  techincally, paronyms of the words ‘mime’ describe all manners of expression and its relation to function, but archaically those of the human face.  whatever:  the book features arthropods that behave like anthropos.

Comment: To be Comic, or not to be Comic?  I care not.  None of the tags which i thought would be pertinent:  childesque, picture-book — whatever, they weren't already used.  Historically, Comic is derived from the word Comedy . . .

Comment: Richard Scarry's books are books with lots of pictures and few words, and have some talking arthropod characters, but most of the characters are other types of animals, so I don't think this description matches any of his books.